# Hibernate Criteria causes ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, ora-00918

I'm running the following code:

```
      Criteria crit = dao.getSesion().createCriteria(TAmbitos.class);
      crit.add( Restrictions.sqlRestriction("translate(upper(nombre), 'ÁÉÍÓÚ', 'AEIOU') like translate(upper(?),'ÁÉÍÓÚ', 'AEIOU')",
              param+"%", Hibernate.STRING));
      crit.add(Restrictions.eq("tipoAmbito", "Empresa"));

      crit.setFetchMode("TAmbitosByPais", FetchMode.JOIN);
      crit.createAlias("TAmbitosByPais", "TAmbitosByPais", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
      crit.add(Restrictions.eq("TAmbitosByPais", ambito));
```

This is causing an `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` exception. The criteria has a table `TAmbitos` which references itself via `TAmbitosByPais` (any given `TAmbitos` row has a field `TAmbitosByIdPais` which references another `TAmbitos`). The resulting SQL is:

```
SELECT this_.id_ambito AS id1_2_1_, this_.depende_empresa AS depende2_2_1_,
   this_.id_zona AS id3_2_1_, this_.pais AS pais2_1_,
   this_.id_cls_soc AS id5_2_1_, this_.tipo_ambito AS tipo6_2_1_,
   this_.nombre AS nombre2_1_, this_.clave_antigua AS clave8_2_1_,
   this_.desactivado AS desactiv9_2_1_,
   tambitosby1_.id_ambito AS id1_2_0_,
   tambitosby1_.depende_empresa AS depende2_2_0_,
   tambitosby1_.id_zona AS id3_2_0_, tambitosby1_.pais AS pais2_0_,
   tambitosby1_.id_cls_soc AS id5_2_0_,
   tambitosby1_.tipo_ambito AS tipo6_2_0_,
   tambitosby1_.nombre AS nombre2_0_,
   tambitosby1_.clave_antigua AS clave8_2_0_,
   tambitosby1_.desactivado AS desactiv9_2_0_
  FROM sac_conf.t_ambitos this_ LEFT OUTER JOIN sac_conf.t_ambitos tambitosby1_
       ON this_.pais = tambitosby1_.id_ambito
 WHERE TRANSLATE (UPPER (nombre), 'ÁÉÍÓÚ', 'AEIOU') LIKE
                                       TRANSLATE (UPPER (?), 'ÁÉÍÓÚ', 'AEIOU')
   AND this_.tipo_ambito = ?
   AND this_.pais = ?
```

As you can see in the WHERE clause, the SQL cannot tell what "nombre" field I am referencing. I can overcome this by adding this_ in the sqlRestriction:

```
crit.add( Restrictions.sqlRestriction("translate(upper(this_.nombre), 'ÁÉÍÓÚ', 'AEIOU') like translate(upper(?),'ÁÉÍÓÚ', 'AEIOU')",
                  nombre+"%", Hibernate.STRING));
```

But I don't know if it is the best solution as I cannot be sure if the SQL will reference always the queried table as this_.There is another way to define the Criteria so "nombre" references `TAmbitos.nombre` and not `TAmbitosByIdPais.nombre`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hibernate Criteria API supports a special `{alias}` placeholder for this case:

```
crit.add( Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
   "translate(upper({alias}.nombre), 'ÁÉÍÓÚ', 'AEIOU') like translate(upper(?),'ÁÉÍÓÚ', 'AEIOU')",
   param+"%", Hibernate.STRING));
```

Comment: In case you're wondering, like I did: Yes, you have to literally type `{alias}` this is not {yourTableAlias} or {myTableAlias} it is a special placeholder like axtavt just explained.

Comment: for my case, I had done `Restrictions.sqlRestriction("id in ...")` and `id` needed to be replaced with `{alias}.id`

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-nativesql) to the rescue:

> Apply a constraint expressed in SQL. **Any occurrences of {alias} will
>   be replaced by the table alias.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Looking at the `Restrictions` [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction(java.lang.String)), I don't think that `SQLQuery` can be used in `Restriction.sqlQuery(String, ...)`. Can a `SQLQuery` be `toString`'d to be a valid argument?